# print variable in parent div span and child div span?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

There is a variable, suppose `item`. It is an array holding two values (`name` and `size`): i.e.

```
item[0]=name;
item[1]=size;
```

Now I print the `name` in parent div span and `size` in child div span, through jQuery.
**How I print the name and size through .parent() and .child() jquery function using?**

```
<div>
    <!--parent div-->
     <span>...Print Name...</span>
     <div>
       <span>...</span>
       <span>...</span>
     </div>
     <div>
       <span>...</span>
       <span>.. Print Size.. ..</span>
     </div>
    <!--close parent div-->
    </div>
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: What is the question? Are you getting it now?

Comment: What? I read it few times and can't understand what do you want to get in result. Do you have some code already? Try to rephrase your question and post code you already have.

Comment: Did you read the jQuery tutorial? http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.text` function of jQuery.

Change your html to:

```
<div>
    <!--parent div-->
     <span class="name">...Print Name...</span>
     <div>
       <span>...</span>
       <span>...</span>
     </div>
     <div>
       <span>...</span>
       <span class="size">.. Print Size.. ..</span>
     </div>
    <!--close parent div-->
    </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".name").text(item[0])
$(".size").text(item[1])
```

Comment: Why `.text`? I would use `.html`.

Comment: @Aleksandr: The values don't contain any HTML, so `.text` suffices.

Comment: Thanks it works..I also use .html ......